# Loading variable to ChartKicks column chart gives Error Loading Chart:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, charts, chartkick

I'm trying to load this variable:

```
  @electro_total = current_user.electros.sum(:electricity_kwst)
```

to a graph in my users/show.html.

I  want the chart to only show one column for now, a column with the sum of all the numbers in each `:electricity_kwst` field.

The variable is currently located in the applications_controller, but I have moved it to the `show` method in `users_controller`, it didn't work either.

I've also tried to hardcode this to the chart, but it didn't work:

```
<%= column_chart [
              {name: "KWst per m&sup2;", data: current_user.electros.sum(:electricity_kwst)}] %>
```

This is the code in my view:

```
<%= column_chart  @electro_total %>
```

It doesn't break the site but it always gives me the error:

```
Error Loading Chart:
```

where the chart should be.

How am I able to do this without getting this error all the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I had to do was to rewrite the code like this:

```
<%= column_chart [
              {name: "KWst per m&sup2;", data: current_user.electros.group_by_year(:created_at).sum(:electricity_kwst)}] %>
```

This gives me the one column I wanted and it shows the sum of all `:electricity_kwst`, in this case for the whole year.